# Reading notes on ledger lines

Tags: notation

I'm trying to read the following stacked notes

[image]

Am I reading it correctly as : D-A-B or is it D-A-D ?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the clef (I assume it is treble clef)? Why do you think that D-A-B is an option?

Comment: @DavidBowling, it's dumb but I didn't count the bar on the A

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a very smart friend of mine says, "Little steps for little feet."  If you are sure the lowest note is D, then count: next line up is two notes higher, so it's F.  Next line up is two notes higher, so it's A.

And so on, for as many ledger lines as you wish.

Answer (score 3):

You ask *whether* it is **D-A-B** *or* **D-A-D**.

One of these you can eliminate right off the bat.

The “A-B” of “D-A-B” is the interval of a **2nd**. The note heads are shifted in such cases to accommodate the necessary space.

[image: A-B note heads are askew]

Your other option, **D-A-D**, happens incidentally to be correct.

If you are having trouble reading the stacked notes—or, for that matter, any other part of the music—it might be prudent to find a copy of the music that is clearer to read.